# How to fix "ImportError: cannot import name Machine" error in ManPy?

Tags: python, simpy

```py
from dream.simulation.imports import Source, Queue, Machine, Exit
from dream.simulation.Globals import runSimulation

# define the objects of the model
S = Source('S1', 'Source', interArrivalTime={'Fixed': {'mean': 0.5}},
              entity='Dream.Part')
Q = Queue('Q1', 'Queue', capacity=1)
M = Machine('M1', 'Machine', processingTime={'Fixed': {'mean': 0.25}})
E = Exit('E1', 'Exit')
# define predecessors and successors for the objects
S.defineRouting(successorList=[Q])
Q.defineRouting(predecessorList=[S], successorList=[M])
M.defineRouting(predecessorList=[Q], successorList=[E])
E.defineRouting(predecessorList=[M])


def main(test=0):
     # add all the objects in a list
     objectList = [S, Q, M, E]
     # set the length of the experiment
     maxSimTime = 1440.0
     # call the runSimulation giving the objects and the length of the experiment
     runSimulation(objectList, maxSimTime)
     # calculate metrics
     working_ratio = (M.totalWorkingTime / maxSimTime) * 100
     # return results for the test
     if test:
          return {"parts": E.numOfExits, "working_ratio": working_ratio}

     # print the results
     print "the system produced", E.numOfExits, "parts"
     print "the total working ratio of the Machine is", working_ratio, "%"


if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Then I got messages as following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "Your directory/dream3/dream/stone/test1.py", line 6, in <module>
    from dream.simulation.imports import Source, Queue, Machine, Exit

  File "your directory\dream3\dream\simulation\imports.py", line 38, in <module>
    from dream.simulation.Machine import Machine

  File "your directory\dream3\dream\simulation\Machine.py", line 36, in <module>
    from SkilledOperatorRouter import SkilledRouter

  File "your directory\dream3\dream\simulation\SkilledOperatorRouter.py", line 32, in <module>
    import Globals

  File "your directory\dream3\dream\simulation\Globals.py", line 29, in <module>
    from Machine import Machine

ImportError: cannot import name Machine
```

Comment: Strange enough, I can run it by inserting a direct import and instantiate a Class before the first line. Would somebody tell me the secret? Thanks.
from dream.simulation.Assembly import Assembly

a = Assembly("101","Assem1",None)


from dream.simulation.imports import Source, Queue, Machine, Exit

from dream.simulation.Globals import runSimulation
..

Comment: Why not use py3 instead of python2?

Comment: I think It is based on Python 2.7, even though not specified in the documentation. It throws a lot of errors like "print xx" with Python 3.6, from which I guess it was developed with Python 2.7. BTW, I find it is very hard to post code in stackoverflow.com. I don't know how to start a new line, especially here.

Answer (score 1):

Good day, Sir!
For what it is worth, somebody had ported this library to Python 3
https://github.com/datarevenue-berlin/manpy
I installed this repo and the examples are working!